# Get the Image object from the Parent Button sender

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp

I want to access the Image object contain in a button in my XAML like this:

```
        <Button Name ="btn1" Click="ButtonClick">
            <Image x:Name="imgbtn1" Source="/Assets/myImage1.png"/>
        </Button>
```

In my code section I have the Click handler and I tried several things to try to get the Image object from the button sender. All solution found so far don't work for me. Here is an example of one of the thing I tried:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = (Image)((Button)sender).Child;
    image.Source = "/Assets/myImage2.png"
}
```

When doing this, Child is highlighted with the error message: 'Button' does not contain a definition for "Child".

How can I get my image from button sender, or what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Content` instead of `child`. `Image` present within `Button` tag denotes its content not child. I have modified your code as your need.

```
<Button Name ="btn1" Click="Button_Click" >
  <Image x:Name="imgbtn1" Source="/Assets/1.jpg"/>
</Button> 

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
  Image image = (Image)((Button)sender).Content;
  image.Source = new BitmapImage() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/2.png") };
}
```